# How was the Earth formed?

Tags: earth-history, earth-system

What events took place in our Solar System which led to formation of the Earth?
I have heard from sources that a big giant star exploded and the Earth was formed. Is this true ?

Comment: why was it downvoted?

Comment: it was down voted because the answer is easy to find and because of the words you did use"i have heard",this is a science site and you need to show that you have atempted to solve the question yourself before asking it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following quote from [Birth of the Earth](http://geology.about.com/od/nutshells/a/aa_earthbirth.htm) explains the current theory/model for the formation of the Solar System:

> Long, long ago (some 5 billion years ago) in a perfectly ordinary place in the galaxy, a supernova exploded, pushing a lot of its heavy-element wreckage into a nearby cloud of hydrogen gas and interstellar dust. The mixture grew hot and compressed under its own gravity, and at its center a new star began to form. Around it swirled a disk of the same material, which grew white-hot from the great compressive forces. That new star became our Sun, and the glowing disk gave rise to Earth and its sister planets. We can see just this sort of thing happening elsewhere in the universe.

Read this article from Wikipedia as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_and_evolution_of_the_Solar_System#Formation_of_planets

Comment: Is there a very good video showing it ...

Comment: There are many good videos showing this process.

Comment: A good place to start is You Tube. Type in *formation of the Earth*  &/or *formation of the solar system*. Try this one, it goes for 2:43 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBwqendK8zc

Comment: I don't agree with this statement: "The mixture grew hot and compressed under its own gravity".  This neglects to mention the influence of gravity waves and how star formation occurs in those regions (e.g. in the arms of the spiral).

Comment: @f.thorpe That's more about how the whole process is kicked off.

Comment: @Spencer: While this is a key question which is still unsolved, I don't think the commenter from 7 years ago will see this comment ;)